# Does My Website Template Include Inbuilt Search functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am working on editing a website template, editing everything directly from its code (not using a CMS). It's going great and I have been able to understand nearly everything to be able to edit the website to my needs, but one thing that I am stumped on is the search functionality. This website has included a lot of plugins e.g. MailChimp functionality to allow the user to edit the website easily. The designer has included a search bar on the website, which currently when you search it will reload the index file. I have done some research on the code to search for any plugins and looked on websites on how I may be able to get this up and going with no luck.

If anyone would be able to help me see if the designer of the template has added any plugins or functionality for actually searching the website that would be great. I am at the point where I need confirmation as to whether I need to start designing search functionality or go with what the template designer has provided (if they have provided anyway).

What I am wanting the end result to be is to be able to search a few keywords and it will show blog posts on a new webpage with the tags that I include within each blog posts code.

I will post what the HTML has below in regards to the search bar and include the JavaScript code relating to the search bar.

Link to the template I am discussing: 
https://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Abstract10/

HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrap">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="#">
      <label>
          <span class="hide-content">Search for:</span>
          <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" autocomplete="off">
      </label>
      <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
  </form>
  <a href="#" id="close-search" class="close-btn">Close</a>
</div>
<!-- end search wrap -->
<div class="triggers">
  <a class="search-trigger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  <a class="menu-toggle" href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
</div>
<!-- end triggers -->
```

JavaScript:

```
var ssSearch = function() {

var searchWrap = $('.search-wrap');
   var searchField = searchWrap.find('.search-field');
   var closeSearch = $('#close-search');
   var searchTrigger = $('.search-trigger');
   var body = $('body');

   searchTrigger.on('click', function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();   
      var $this = $(this);

      body.addClass('search-visible');
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('.search-wrap').find('.search-field').focus();
      }, 100);

   });


   closeSearch.on('click', function(){
      var $this = $(this);

      if(body.hasClass('search-visible')){
         body.removeClass('search-visible');
         setTimeout(function(){
            $('.search-wrap').find('.search-field').blur();
         }, 100);
      }
   });

   searchWrap.on('click',  function(e){
    if( !$(e.target).is('.search-field') ) {        
        closeSearch.trigger('click');           
    }
   });

   searchField.on('click', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
   });

   searchField.attr({placeholder: 'Search', autocomplete: 'off'});

   };
```

Comment: Realistically, search functionality has to be written that will tailor fit your site. No-one knows what data you need searching for so you have to write that yourself. Some Wordpress plugins do help but still no way near writing your own custom search. In more realistic scenarios, you have to index your site manually in a custom search engine like solr or elastic search

Comment: So the answer is no, it is very unlikely that there is a search functionality built in to a template. All the code is doing is showing and hiding a search input box.

Comment: From the demo page, it doesn't appear to be functional, so you can assume that it was never implemented, or else that would probably be showcased.

Comment: If you are just searching for text within a single page then use Ctrl+F - all built into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Search functionality is not written in the above code provided by you.
You can use various search plugins based upon the backend technology which you are using. You can also use elasticsearch server provided by AWS to keep your search results indexed. You can then ping the search endpoint to get results in the order you want.

Check out the [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/details/) to learn more about elasticsearch.